# How to access Environment Variables, created in Context, in my config.yml file?

Tags: android, sh, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Since I cannot push my `jks file` and `keystore.properties` file to my public Github repository, I followed [Signing Android APK’s with CircleCI](http://deathstartup.com/signing-android-apks-with-circleci/) and [Continuous Integration and Deployment with Android, the right way](https://brianlusina.github.io/tech/ci-with-android-and-circleci/) posts. But none of them show how to access an environment variable created in [Contexts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/). I need these context environment variables to download jks file and export secret credentials such as `key alias` to `keystore.properties` file which is executed in my `.circleci/ci-scripts/circleci_env_setup.sh` bash script. Even I followed the [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/) I get the following error:

Keystore file is missing, performing download for "" at ""
curl: option -o: requires parameter

And this proves that I cannot access `STORE_FILE` and `KEY_STORE_URI` environments correctly. You can see my all circle ci work from [this repository](https://github.com/melomg/Capstone-Project/tree/master/.circleci). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `workflows` key in your CircleCI Config, you need to apply to context the job: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/

If you don't need workflows (you're using a single job), you don't need to use contexts at all. Just use private environment variables from your project's settings page.